# How to update data based on cell's background color

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, add-on

I have a google sheet with some data in it. I have a column with different cell colors. I want to upload data next to that column based on the cell's color.

These are color instructions:

```
Orange  Negatived added
Blue    To be negatived out
Green   Converted
Yellow  Not sure
Grey    Not to be touched
Red     Cancel Negative.
```

I'm not a pro on this sort of things. I have been wandering for more than 5 hours but didn't find any helpful resource to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [@player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) is also correct, but you can do this without a third-party addon by using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

Here is how it looks:

[image: Final result on the sheet]

Here is how to use it:

[image: How the formula is used]

Here is the code:

```
function doActionBasedOnColor(cellA1) { //cellA1 is the A1 notation of the cell (it's position)
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellA1);
  switch (cell.getBackground()) {
    case "#ff9900": //Orange
      return "Negatived added"
      break;

    case "#0000ff": //Blue
      return "To be negatived out"
      break;

    case "#00ff00": //Green
      return "Converted"
      break;

    case "#ffff00": //Yellow
      return "Not sure"
      break;

    case "#b7b7b7": //Grey
      return "Not to be touched"
      break;

    case "#ff0000": //Red
      return "Cancel Negative"
      break;

    default:
      return "Cell Background is: " + cell.getBackground();
      break;
  }
}
```

If you need to use the select and drag functionality, you can do so by changing the function to:

```
function doActionBasedOnColor(row,col) {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, col);
  //...
```

and the formula to:
`=doActionBasedOnColor(COLUMN(A1),ROW(A1))`

I hope this helps!

Comment: @ ZektorH This is amazing, I know how to code but I didn't know I can use js for this. Thanks mate, I just have one problem when I call this function and drag it down to the bottom of the column the argument of the function doesn't change according to the row number. e.g; C1,C2,C3 and so on. How do I do that

Comment: Hello @Rose, you can't do that in a normal way, however, I have updated the answer to have that possibility as well.

Comment: it just prints the background color with the highest hex value. Maybe I'm making a mistake while selecting a cell. The data is in C column and I'm doing this =doSomeAction(Column(c1),Row(A1)) also I have tried this =doSomeAction(Column(c1),Row(c1))

Comment: This can only handle a single Cell. The usage of the formula is: =doActionBasedOnColor(COLUMN(C1),ROW(C1)) . It will only show the background color if the color is not one of the specified above.

Comment: it was working fine on my sheet but now it just gets loading and doesn't display anything.

Comment: When you replaced the function did you remove all code or keep it unchanged after the "//..." ?

Comment: I just changed the first line as you suggested to dynamically change the cell and it was working very fine but now it doesn't display me anything it just gets loading and then stop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201328/discussion-between-zektorh-and-rose).

Answer (score 1):

not possible without script or addon...

you will need this addon for that: **https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb**

then you can use `COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR` function so your final formula would be like:

```
=IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1, C$1)=1, "Negatived added", 
 IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1, C$2)=1, "To be negatived out", 
 IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1, C$3)=1, "Converted", 
 IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1, C$4)=1, "Not sure", 
 IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1, C$5)=1, "Not to be touched", 
 IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(A1, C$6)=1, "Cancel Negative", ))))))
```

where C1:C6 contains sample colors